# Maven Surefire plugin + parallel build

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

In our fairly large project (around 600 maven modules) we've decided to try maven's parallel build capability. So I've installed maven 3.3 and tried to run unit tests.

I've figured out that sometimes our unit tests fail. If I run the module 'alone' it works, and of course if we run maven 'sequentially' (no -T option) it also works.

So, I think that its due to the fact that sometimes tests interfere, probably some static code or shared instances cause these failures.

My question is, what is the optimal way to run the unit tests of my project?
I'm aware of option to spawn JVM upon each test running, but since we have thousands of unit tests I'm afraid such a build would last forever :)

AFAIK there are 3 possible solutions:

1. Just skip the tests, compile/package/install everything in parallel. And then run tests separately. This approach can be feasible for jenkins, but I can be a hassle for developers who are just accustomed to run **mvn install**
2. Somehow extend surefire plugin that it would automatically rerun N times the unit test if it fails. If the test fails, say 50% of times - its really unstable and should cause the whole build failure. I wouldn't like to use a **@RunWith** annotation because of two reasons: a. There are just to many tests to update with this annotation and we don't have a base class or something. b. Some tests already contain this annotation (for power mock for example, or junit rules)
3. Somehow extend surefire plugin to run tests in different classloader. This solution has come to my mind due to the fact that maven seems to run multiple modules with the same classloader (I've just put 2 tests that print the address of classloader in two different submodules and ensured that the classloader is the same, the addresses are identical). This solution looks interesting but relatively complicated.

Before diving to any of these solution and talking to my managers, 
I would appreciate if someone could comment on one of these solutions/provide another one. I Just don't want to reinvent the wheel and hopefully save some time :)

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: to be honest the simplest answer is. Fix those tests cause there are two things they a likely no unit tests or doing things wrong as you already mentioned...BTW: I would be interested how long your build is running and why didn't you start using -T option with earlier versions of Maven (3.1.1, 3.2.5...) ? How many test do you have?

Comment: Thanks, in theory you're right, being an advocate of TDD, I completely agree with you: these tests are not really unit tests and probably they do things wrong exactly as you've mentioned. However in a project that already has hundreds of such tests (all in all we have thousands of unit tests written by more than one hundred developers) I just can't remove them altogether/fix by myself. As for the maven version it kind of wasn't my decision (otherwise I would use gradle with its incremental build :)) Thanks for the comment in any case.

Comment: I know what you are talking about...I have project with more than 400 modules (ca. 6500 tests)...But if those tests are not fixed you can't parallelize  them...or they should be named different to run them as integration tests in different phase...But i'm interested how long your build takes and how many tests you have..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about running each test class in a separate JVM? (And possibly reuse the forked JVMs in other tests).

Honestly, it looks like you didn't give it a shoot. Check out the doc https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

Just a copy paste of the example:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19</version>
  <configuration>
    <forkCount>3</forkCount>
    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
        <databaseSchema>MY_TEST_SCHEMA_${surefire.forkNumber}</databaseSchema>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
    <workingDirectory>FORK_DIRECTORY_${surefire.forkNumber}</workingDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

By the way, surefire can re-run failing tests: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html. I'm just afraid you won't be able to set a threshold.

Also not that forking can make debugging (e.g., attaching a debugger) quite difficult.

From my experience, not all the surefire settings are compatible with *forking* so you may need to go step by step while tuning the configuration to see what is actually working and what is not.